# How do I sort a whole pandas dataframe by one column, moving the rows grouped in 3s

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, bioinformatics

I have a dataframe with genes (ensembl IDs and common name), homologs, counts, and totals in orders of three as such:

```
Index Zebrafish Homolog  Human Homolog    Total
0     ENSDARG00000019949 ENSG00000149257 
1     serpinh1b          SERPINH1
2     2                  2                4
3     ENSDARG00000052437 ENSG00000268975
4     mia                MIA-RAB4B
5     2                  0                2
6     ENSDARG00000057992 ENSG00000134363
7     fstb               FST
8     0                  3                3
9     ENSDARG00000045580 ENSG00000139329
10    lum                LUM
11    15                 15               30

etc...
```

I want to sort these rows by the totals in descending order. such that all the rows are kept intact in groups of 3 in the orders shown. The ideal output would be:

```
Index Zebrafish Homolog  Human Homolog    Total
0     ENSDARG00000045580 ENSG00000139329
1     lum                LUM
2     15                 15               30    
3     ENSDARG00000019949 ENSG00000149257 
4     serpinh1b          SERPINH1
5     2                  2                4
6     ENSDARG00000057992 ENSG00000134363
7     fstb               FST
8     0                  3                3
9     ENSDARG00000052437 ENSG00000268975
10    mia                MIA-RAB4B
11    2                  0                2

etc...
```

I tried making the totals for each in all 3 rows and then sorting using dataframe.sort.values() and removing the previous 2 rows for each clump of 3 but it didnt work properly. Is there a way to group the rows together into clumps of 3, then sort them to maintain that structure? Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Update #1

If i try to use the code:

```
df['Total'] = df['Total'].bfill().astype(int)
df = df.sort_values(by='Total', ascending=False)
```

to add values to the total for each group of 3 and then sort, It partially works, but scrambles the code like this:

```
Index Zebrafish Homolog  Human Homolog    Total
0     ENSDARG00000045580 ENSG00000139329  30
1     lum                LUM              30
2     15                 15               30    
4     serpinh1b          SERPINH1         4
3     ENSDARG00000019949 ENSG00000149257  4
5     2                  2                4
8     0                  3                3
7     fstb               FST              3
6     ENSDARG00000057992 ENSG00000134363  3
9     ENSDARG00000052437 ENSG00000268975  2
11    2                  0                2
10    mia                MIA-RAB4B        2
```

etc...

And even worse is if multiple genes have the same total counts, the rows will become interchanged between genes which becomes confusing

Is this a dead end? Maybe I should just rewrite the code a different way :(

Comment: You DataFrame is awkward. It is poorly organized. All data related to a sample should be in one row. Did you construct it yourself or import?

Comment: I constructed it myself in this format because it would be easier to manually look through the genes one by one after I've sorted it. Just sorting it now is an issue :/

Comment: I strongly suggest that you construct it in a proper way. You can convert it to any viewable form later.

Comment: Not really sure it makes sense to put all the homolog ensembl IDs, original gene names, and counts in all one row for each gene though? In my actual code, I'm calling the ensembl API for not only human homologs, but mouse, rat, drosopila, c.elegans, and other homologs for each gene in a list of say 500 genes. The number of columns would become ridiculously long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a second key to keep the records together on sorting , see below:

```
df.Total= df.Total.bfill()                                                                                           
df["helper"]= np.arange(len(df))//3 
df= df.sort_values(["Total","helper"])
df= df.drop(columns="helper")
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your totals are missing values and that helps in this case

- Approach 1

```
df['Total'] = df['Total'].bfill().astype(int)
df['idx'] = np.arange(len(df)) // 3
df = df.sort_values(by=['Total', 'idx'], ascending=False)
df = df.drop(['idx'], axis=1)
```

```
     Zebrafish_Homolog    Human_Homolog  Total
9   ENSDARG00000045580  ENSG00000139329     30
10                 lum              LUM     30
11                  15               15     30
0   ENSDARG00000019949  ENSG00000149257      4
1            serpinh1b         SERPINH1      4
2                    2                2      4
6   ENSDARG00000057992  ENSG00000134363      3
7                 fstb              FST      3
8                    0                3      3
3   ENSDARG00000052437  ENSG00000268975      2
4                  mia        MIA-RAB4B      2
5                    2                0      2
```

Note how the index stays the same, if you don't want that then reset_index()

`df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`

- Approach 2

A more manual way of sorting.
The approach is to sort the index and then `loc` the df. It looks complicated but it's just subtract ints from a list. Note the process doesn't happen on the `df` until the end so there should be no speed issue for a larger `df`.

```
# Sort by total
df = df.reset_index().sort_values('Total', ascending=False)
# Get the index of the sorted values
uniq_index = df[df['Total'].notnull()]['index'].values

# Create the new index
index = uniq_index .repeat(3)
groups = [-2, -1, 0] * (len(df) // 3)

# Update so everything is in order
new_index = index + groups

# Apply to the dataframe
df = df.loc[new_index]
```

```
     Zebrafish_Homolog    Human_Homolog  Total
0   ENSDARG00000045580  ENSG00000139329    NaN
1                  lum              LUM    NaN
2                   15               15   30.0
9   ENSDARG00000019949  ENSG00000149257    NaN
10           serpinh1b         SERPINH1    NaN
11                   2                2    4.0
3   ENSDARG00000057992  ENSG00000134363    NaN
4                 fstb              FST    NaN
5                    0                3    3.0
6   ENSDARG00000052437  ENSG00000268975    NaN
7                  mia        MIA-RAB4B    NaN
8                    2                0    2.0
12  ENSDARG00000052437  ENSG00000268975    NaN
13                 mia        MIA-RAB4B    NaN
14                   2                0    2.0
```

Comment: I see. I've done that and it works partially in that the totals are kept in groups of 3, but the orders are messed up due to the sorting algorithm not taking into account the differences in the homolog values between the 3 rows.

Comment: Sure. I dont know how to post code in comments, sorry this is my first post. but the format that I showed earlier (ENSEMBL ID, gene name, count, ENSEMBL ID, gene name, count, ENSEMBL ID, gene name, count, etc...) becomes scrambled randomly as you move down the column. for a particular column, it might look like(count, ensembl ID, gene name, gene name, count, ensembl ID, count, ensembl ID, gene name, etc...). I hope this makes sense

Comment: Great, this works. Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: No problem `+1` as it helps a lot